# Catching url in htaccess rewrite condition

Tags: .htaccess, regex

I got this url

```
/search/renttype-all.place-all.type-all.bedrooms-all.0.0/
```

I want to get the text after the second "/" and the third "/". The URL can end at the third "/" or go on with more text and "/". I have been trying with a lot of rules but never got any to work. My last try was

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)/$ index.php?Search=0&Arg=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)/(.+)$ index.php?Search=0&Arg=$1 [NC]
```

Anyone that can show me how to make a rule that works? :)
Thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/ index.php?Search=0&Arg=$1 [NC]
```